# How to update nested attributes in ruby on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models services and comments
the comments code is(comment.rb):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :service
belongs_to :user
end
```

the service.rb file :

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a    [:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I am successfully updating the comments using the view given below :

```
<%= form_for(@service) do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :comments, @comment do |c| %>
<%= c.text_area :content,:rows =>10, :cols => 60, :class => 'editme'%><br />
<%end%>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

The update method in service controller is given below :

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @service.update(service_params)

    @service.update(:comments_attributes => {:user_id => 9 })
    format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(:sname, :scategory, :cat_description,   :min_name, :min_description, :min_start_date, :min_end_date,comments_attributes: [:content,:service_id,:user_id,:uname])
end
```

The following collection is being passed from the view to the controller as is updating the comment table correctly.

```
"service"=>{"comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"<p>hh</p>"}}}
```

Now the comment table has user_id column which i am trying to update from session[:user_id] in the update method . I have tried the few options but none of them are working.

```
# @comment.user_id=session[:user_id]
    #@service.comments.assign_attributes.first(id:  '26',{comments_attributes: {user_id: "#{session[:user_id]}"}})
```

could you please let me know what i am doing wrong here and how should i update the user_id column in comment table in the update method of service controller , i am new to ruby on rails any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't say i've ever done something like `@service.update(:comments_attributes => {:user_id => 9 })` . It doesn't feel right. How about not using nested attributes?

Comment: I know why it doesn't feel right. There is no `id` to which update can reference. Your example of `"service"=>{"comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"<p>hh</p>"}}}` Has `0` which represents a new record. `@service.update(:comments_attributes => {:user_id => 9 })` Has no `id`. I would rework it to not use nested attributes and create a comment directly  as it seems all you are interested it in making a comment, not also editing a `service`

Comment: Since you have a user `:id`, I would assume you are using some sort of login system. Shouldn't it have something like `current_user`? Your user's ID should come from within, not from params, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to remove `:user_id` from `params.require(...).permit(...)` method, and not to use it on the view for sending it as a parameter in `comments_attributes`. Since, it'll defeat the purpose of having strong params. Instead update the params hash after filtering them in the contoller:

```
def service_params
  updated_service_params = params.require(:service).permit(:sname, :scategory, :cat_description, :min_name, :min_description, :min_start_date, :min_end_date, comments_attributes: [:content, :service_id, :uname])
  updated_service_params[:comments_attributes].each{ |k, v| v.merge!(user_id: session[:user_id]) } if updated_service_params && updated_service_params[:comments_attributes]
  updated_service_params
end
```

So now your `update` method can be:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @service.update(service_params)

      format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Surya. That works! However to make it work I'd to include user_id in the list of allowed comments_attributes in service_params method. Otherwise I was getting unpermitted parameter user_id in the log. Do you know why would this be the case? Also I had to call update_comment_attributes before invoking update method.View was returning an array of hashes to controller and maybe because of this when I tried create my own hash using @service.update(:comments_attributes=>{:user_id => 9 }) - I was getting no implicit conversion of String into Integer error. Any idea if it can be done this way?

Comment: @pari : My bad. Please look at the updated revision.